# Action bar navigation modes are deprecated in Android L

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation, android-5.0-lollipop

Taking a look at the API diff report for the Android "L" preview, I see that all methods related to navigation modes in the `ActionBar` class (such as `setNavigationMode()`, `addTab()`, `selectTab()`, &c). are now deprecated.

The documentation explains:

> Action bar navigation modes are deprecated and not supported by inline
>   toolbar action bars. Consider using other common navigation patterns
>   instead.

What is the supposed replacement?

Also, is "inline toolbar action bars" a new concept? I don't think I've heard of it before.

Comment: Where did you find the docs for the L Preview?

Comment: @KlassenK It's not yet integrated into the main documentation, but you can download it from http://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html

Comment: For setNavigationList what did you use

Comment: @matiash your above link(having 7 likes) is broken now

Comment: @ShirishHerwade Yes, because it was merged into the main documentation when Android 5.0 was released. In any case, you can now find the deprecation notice in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode%28int%29

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The new [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) adds [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), providing a tab implementation that matches the [material design guidelines for tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html). A complete walkthrough of how to implement Tabs and `ViewPager` can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ)

**Now deprecated:** The [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) is part of the support library (and has been for some time) and serves as a direct replacement. If you prefer the newer Google Play style tabs, you can use the [PagerSlidingTabStrip library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) or modify either of the Google provided examples [SlidingTabsBasic](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) or [SlidingTabsColors](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html) as explained in this [Dev Bytes video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk).

Comment: This is a direct replacement in portrait mode, with the bonus of making it easy to use an extended Material-type header. However, in landscape mode the ActionBar tabs automatically move up into the action bar itself, freeing important screen area. Anybody know a clean way to manage this with the support library?

Comment: [This Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+LucasRocha/posts/eGR9P5mSRXm) about Toolbars has a comment from Chris Banes, one of the Google developers who built this new functionality, stating that the support library work to support this change is in work. I'd expect more information closer to Android L's release.

Comment: The developer document still says using Action Bar Tab. Simlpy not updated yet?http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#swipe-tabs

Comment: This is a replacement for NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS but not for NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST :/

Comment: @Geobert - `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` is much easier, given that all that did was add a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) and some callback helpers.

Comment: What is the replacement for `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`? Mine lists it as deprecated...

Comment: The video linked to with instructions for implementing tabs is good, but the tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs) it links to at the end is the same one which uses the deprecated NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS, the very reference which led me to this SO question in the first place.

Comment: It's amazing that they still use a feature in their offical "training" guides that has been deprecated for years now.

Comment: 4 years and their official document hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 20):

Now that the Android 5.0 docs are available, we have the [official documentation for the Toolbar widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html):

> A standard toolbar for use within application content.
>
> A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within
>   application layouts. *While an action bar is traditionally part of an
>   Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, a Toolbar
>   may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view
>   hierarchy*.

A `Toolbar` widget can also be used to replace the action bar:

> An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the action bar for
>   an Activity using the `setActionBar()` method.

The deprecation of tabs in the action bar is most probably due to this, since toolbars cannot contain tab themselves.

Also, it's available for previous Android verions via the appcompat library. See [this post by Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) for more information. An excerpt:

> Android 5.0 introduces a new Toolbar widget. This is a generalization
>   of the ActionBar pattern but gives you **much** more control and
>   flexibility in using it. Toolbar is a view in your hierarchy just like
>   any other, making it easier to interleave with the rest of your views,
>   animate, react to scroll events.

Comment: "much more control and flexibility" is only nice if there are sensible and easy to use defaults. If something is flexible but you need 20 lines here and there to make it work, I don't consider it a win...

Comment: @TWiStErRob I agree. Emphasis his, not mine :)

Comment: @TWiStErRob I feel the same way...Google better watch out, this kind of activity is reminding me of the old Microsoft

Answer (score 13):

It seems like they added a new Class named `android.widget.Toolbar` that extends `ViewGroup`. Also they added a new method `setActionBar(Toolbar)` in `Activity`. I haven't tested it yet, but it looks like you can wrap all kinds of `TabWidgets`, `Spinners` or custom views into a `Toolbar` and use it as your Actionbar.

Comment: Can someone share if they tried anything with the Toolbar widget or knows how it is intended to work. Also is it included in the compatibility package?

Comment: Have a look at https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/aanbpbAcUKW?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=aa354b61eb-Android_Weekly_110&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-aa354b61eb-337825901

Comment: Thank u very much for the link..so now if I want to develop an app that would be according to the new material guidelines, I should probably wait for the toolbar to become available, because if I use the actionbar I would be using everything that is deprecated.. ?

Comment: The ActionBar will still be a standard design pattern. Only the navigation modes will be deprecated (Tabs or Spinner). See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

Comment: Well you'll still have to implement for Android <= 4.4.x and Android L because you know how long it takes for new Android versions to distribute :(... Unless the Toolbar will be part of the support lib, what I don't see coming right now.

Comment: From the above link that you posted, it seems like they are working on compatibility for the toolbar, but you're right about the time it will take for us to see it in action and actually use it. So thx for the links, you at least helped me make up my mind.

Comment: Oops, I didn't have the chance to read chris banes comment. I just remembered that there was a post in the current android weekly about your problem. Sorry for that : )

Comment: I think that it is related to the question.. the new i/o 2014 application's apk is available for download, and as you can see from https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/PD6MS3feXTT, there are plenty of toolbar styles used. We just have to wait for the source code, and explore it then :(

Answer (score 4):

The new `Toolbar` cannot be used for inflating multiple line objects, so it is impossible to add Tabs to it.
If you want to use a `Toolbar` like a `TabWidget` you can insert some Tab Objects to it, but only with the old Holo style.

[Here](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs) there is a custom Library that uses v7 `Toolbar` like `TabWidget` with the new Material Design animations, but it uses the same methods from the old `ActionBar Tabs`, so you can attach your `ViewPager` to it.

Answer (score 3):

For 'replacement' of deprecated ActionBar, I changed the type of my ActionBar-type variables to PagerTabStrip, as per (old code in comment):

```
// ActionBar bigActionBar;
PagerTabStrip bigActionBar;
```

A 'replacement' for ~actionBar's .selectTab(tabindex) was to use my associated ViewPager's .setCurrentItem(int) method, like this (old code in comment):

```
/*
ActionBar.Tab eventTab = bigActionBar.getTabAt(2);
bigActionBar.selectTab(eventTab);
*/
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this solution suited me quite nicely:

In the layout xml file that contains the viewpager, add the a PagerTabStrip as shown:

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#996633"
    android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
```

To control page titles, add a switch statement to your ViewPager file:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
{
    switch (position)
    {
    case 0:
        return "Page 1";

    case 1:
        return "Page 2";

    case 2:
        return "Page 3";

    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FragmentTabHost is also an option.

This code is from Android developer's site:

```
/**
 * This demonstrates how you can implement switching between the tabs of a
 * TabHost through fragments, using FragmentTabHost.
 */
public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial which includes this answer, so it might help someone http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/user-interface/compositeitems/tabhost

Answer (score 0):

I found these tutorials helpful while putting together an action bar (now the 'tool bar' - argh) that supports sliding tabs with Material Design:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fl0xMuo10yA

http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

You sort of have to synthesize these resources to match your particular situation. For example, you may not want to manually create the tabs in the same style that the exoguru.com tutorial did.

Comment: Second link is dead.

Comment: @jcaruso that's not my fault as that domain seems to be expired. The youtube video is still relevant though

Comment: @kip2 I agree, it's not your fault. However, I suggest as everyone suggest, avoid using links to explain answers because of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me to handle the deprecated navigation toolbar by using toolbar v7 widget appcompat.

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Feed Detail");
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //goToWhere
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a suitable replacement for when you have three to five screens of equal importance is the BottomNavigationActivity,this can be used to switch fragments.

You will notice a wizard exists for this in Android Studio, take care however as Android Studio has a tendency to produce overly complex boiler plate code.

A tutorial can be found here:
https://android.jlelse.eu/ultimate-guide-to-bottom-navigation-on-android-75e4efb8105f

Another quality tutorial can be found at Android Hive here:
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/