# Actions bars android L

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, appbar

[image]

How can I create App bars (Action bar) like displayed on this screenshot?
And how can I attach App bar to any view or card view? And is it possible with Android L SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at article [Action Bar simplification and Toolbar](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/aanbpbAcUKW?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=aa354b61eb-Android_Weekly_110&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-aa354b61eb-337825901).
Seems like you should use new Toolbar widget instead of ActionBar.
Also here [answer on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24477784/1243447)

Answer (score 1):

It is the new Toolbar widget.

Currenty this widget is supported only on Android-L.

You can put it in the xml layout:

```
<CardView>
     <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp">
    </Toolbar>
</CardView>
```

Then you can get it in your java code, with something like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        //Title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle("MY toolbar");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");

        //Menu
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.toolbar_menu);

        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_share:
                        Toast.makeText(ToolbarActivity.this,"Share",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```