# Instead of action bar tabs

Tags: android

I am using this tab system:http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ and this is using action bar tabs.I built everything on this system.But I heard action bar tabs are deprecated with Android "L".What should I change in my code ? I don't want to change all tab system (if it's possible)

Also action bar tabs styling is not useful.I want to change tab background and indicator.

What can I do for to achive these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PagerTabStrip which is part of the Support Library

Or the PagerSlidingTabs https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

[Action bar navigation modes are deprecated in Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l)

More info:

The android.support.v13.app package has adapters which are compatible with native fragments (if you aren't keen on using support fragments)

Add the v13 support dependency to your project to use them.

Comment: I have to change my fragments ?

Comment: @SerkaySarıman what do you mean by change? are you using native fragments at the moment?