# Actionbar tabs or SlidingTabsLayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I want to have some tabs in my action bar. The official Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)
uses

> actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)

which is now deprecated.
So i wonder what should i use instead ? [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) ?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/24473213/82788

Comment: oh sry didn't foind it can / should i delete my question ?

Comment: If the other one answers it to your satisfaction... :)