# Alternative to ActionBar.OnNavigationListener ?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, deprecated

I am trying to use ActionBar.OnNavigationListener, it says:

**The type ActionBar.OnNavigationListener is deprecated. This interface was deprecated in API level 21**

What is the alternative API to this and how should this be handled??

Comment: The alternative API is to do something else for navigation, such as a nav drawer (e.g., `DrawerLayout`).

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l)