# PageAdapter and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to set up sliding tabs on top of an activity. I want this result :

[image]

I'm following the explanations of this example : http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html

And I'm also looking at this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk

I'm doing so because of this post : [Action bar navigation modes are deprecated in Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l)

I have 3 fragments for each of my tab. Each inflates a different layout and do different things. Now I need to connect them to my `PageAdapter`. I've already used an adaptor for a ListView. I used `getView` with the `position` to do my work

However with this `PageAdapter` I'm not sure what I need to proceed. Should I use this method to create my fragment :

```
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
```

and if so, how should it be done ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement a `FragmentPagerAdapter` like this:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new FirstFragment();
    case 1:
        return new TwoFragment();
    case 2:
        return new ThreeFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}


}
```

and set it to viewpager adapter:

```
 mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```