# how to customize the animations of the navigation drawer when opening

Tags: android, animation, navigation, drawer

I have an app with a navigation drawer and tab bar (view pager) and when the nav. drawer is opened, 3 distinct animations occur, which together make the experience very un-smooth (clunky).

1. the navigation drawer opens
2. the tab bar disappears
3. the action bar disappears (i am hiding the action bar when nav drawer is opened).

all these combine to create a non-optimal experience.

is there a way to reduce/eliminate these animations but keep the sliding of the nav drawer animation?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use action bar tabs because they are deprecated (find an alternative [Action bar navigation modes are deprecated in Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l)).

Second, optimize fragments that are contained in ViewPager.

Third, optimize everything else (like navigation drawer listview)