# Replacement for ActionBar navigation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, deprecated, android-5.0-lollipop

I upgraded to Android 5.0, API 21, and all my navigation for tabs and lists in ActionBar have been deprecated. I have yet to found any reasonable replacement that allow for the inclusion of lists and tabs as my app requires.

What new methods can I use to replace the deprecated methods:
For the lists:

```
// Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // DEPRACATED
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST); // NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST DEPRECATED
```

For the tabbed navigation:
The class:

```
public class GroupIndFriendActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener { // TabListener DEPRECATED
```

...

```
// Set up the action bar.
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); // DEPRECATED
```

...

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,                 // DEPRECATED 
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
```

Comment: For tabs, use `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip` or any of the various third-party open source ones).

Comment: @CommonsWare Did you read the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html, it explicitly uses methods that are deprecated: `final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

Comment: Yes, I did read the docs. I did not say to use action bar tabs with `ViewPager`. I said to use `PagerTabStrip` or any of the various third-party open source indicators, as you can tell by reading my comment. You can see an example of using `PagerTabStrip` [elsewhere in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip). I have filed [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82566) to get the documentation improved.

Comment: "using third-party solutions is a bad idea" -- you are welcome to your opinion. Few people that I would consider to be Android experts would agree. That being said, `PagerTabStrip` is part of the Android Support Package, and therefore may be more amenable to your restrictive conditions.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there some sort of tutorial to allow for adding this navigation?

Comment: You can see an example of using `PagerTabStrip` [elsewhere in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip), as noted previously. Also, here is a sample app from my book that uses `PagerTabStrip`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Indicator

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, what about the drop down menu in the actionbar, noting that navigation mode list is deprecated. How can I add a drop down menu to the menu bar that will be compatible with api 21 and previous? I tried toolbar with a spinner, but it required minsdkversion to be 21 to work

Comment: Google would probably recommend a nav drawer. In principle, the `NAVIGATION_MODE_CUSTOM` should support a `Spinner` on all relevant API levels, though I have not tried it, and be sure to use the themed `Context` you can get from the `ActionBar` when you try setting it up.

Comment: Can I place a spinner in a navigation drawer? I wish to have a dropdown for selecting the day of the week

Comment: Usually you would put a list or an expandable list in there, but there should be no reason why a `Spinner` would not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action bar navigation modes are deprecated in Android L](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PageTabStrip](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) or [App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) (the link will provide you detailed step by step guide how to setup App bar)

This stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l) might be of help for you.