# how to set the NavigationMode in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When I tried to use `ActionBar` and specify the `navigationMode` eclipse says it is deprecated without suggesting the recommende one to use instead.

what should i use instead of `this.actionBar.setNavigationMode(mode)`?

Comment: You can still call that method, you just need to be aware that it may be unsupported in the future. The best solution is to revise your app's design/navigation according to the newest guidelines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24473213 good reading.

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternate method to use from the now deprecated `setNavigationMode` since the `Toolbar` is basically a stripped down version of the actionbar where you put in the views you want inside the toolbar.

for example if you wanted to replicate the Dropdown navigation mode you would put a spinner inside your toolbar