# what can I use instead of setNavigationMode

Tags: android

Since setNavigationMode has been deprecated in API level 21 what can I use instead of setNavigationMode to create tabs.Is there an alternative library which I can use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action bar navigation modes are deprecated in Android L](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Action bar navigation modes are deprecated in **API level 21**.

So, it is not just `setNavigationMode` but other stuff related to Action Bar such as `addTab()`, `selectTab()`, too are deprecated.

Other possible Alternatives:
1. [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html): This is part of Android support library, and It is intended to be used as a child view of a ViewPager widget in  XML layout.
2.[Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html): Added in API Level 21, is a new class `android.widget.Toolbar`. As per Android docs, A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts.

ToolBar is a view placed in your view hierarchy that provides a similar, but more focused, API to the action bar.

An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the action bar for an `Activity` using the `setActionBar`() method.

It depends on your app design as to which one you may want to choose as vis-a-vis replacement.

Check [THIS](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/aanbpbAcUKW?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=aa354b61eb-Android_Weekly_110&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-aa354b61eb-337825901#%20IanLake/posts/aanbpbAcUKW?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=aa354b61eb-Android_Weekly_110&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-aa354b61eb-337825901) Link for more info.