# Getting error deprecated ( setNavigationMode(int), addTab(ActionBar.Tab) , addTab(ActionBar.Tab) , addTab(ActionBar.Tab)

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm new to android development and, I'm getting deprecated errors in this code, please someone show me how to fix this code without errors.

> - The method `setNavigationMode(int)` from the type `ActionBar` is deprecated.
> - The method `addTab(ActionBar.Tab)` from the type `ActionBar` is deprecated.
> - The method `setSelectedNavigationItem(int)` from the type `ActionBar` is deprecated.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        
        context = this;
        String mBaseFolderPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Folder2"
                + File.separator;
        if (!new File(mBaseFolderPath).exists()) {
            new File(mBaseFolderPath).mkdir();
        }

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new FBTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         */
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Adapter.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class VDTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public VDTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
               
                return new VDFragment();
            case 1:
                
                return new ADFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }
    
}
```

Code 2.

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
            Log.e("UPDATED", " SELECTED");
            final DownloadsFragment fragment = ((VDFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":1"));
            fragment.updateVD();
```

ERROR.

> - The method `getPosition()` from the type `ActionBar.Tab` is deprecated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646486/the-type-actionbar-tab-is-deprecated

Comment: deprectaed means the error itself is no more in use, instead android has provided anything else, can you please tell me wats the use of it exactly? @Agatha

Comment: @Pratik Dasa , can I use the deprecated code for future android versions if I go without solving it? I don't know, I hope It should be solved, am I right?

Im using minSdkVersion="11" targetSdkVersion="25"

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya , I have already seen that, since I'm a newbie I need the above code should be resolved by someone, though I can understand It well :(

Comment: Can you send me your full project in my email? Let me check and try to solve it and you want to make a demo for it only?@AgathaJannet

Comment: @ Pratik Dasa, I have another problem, I will mail you.

Comment: okay no worries @AgathaJannet

Comment: Did not get it still @AgathaJannet

Comment: Now please check it

Comment: http://anusreeanair.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-fetch-images-from-sdcard-and.html check this. @AgathaJannet