# How to hide just the pager tabs (but not the action bar) in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager to display tabs in Android, but in a circumstance, I want to display a fragment on top of the pager/tabs, but NOT on top of the ActionBar. If I hide the action bar, they both disappear. If I don't do it, I can't find a way to get rid of pager's tab bar (or whatever it's called). Here is a visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

How can I hide that bar without hiding the action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it by setting a new navigation mode.

Use `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)` to hide them

Use `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` to show them again

Edit:

Please note that the `setNavigationMode` methods are deprecated in Android Lollipop.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get rid of tabs in actionbar

```
setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)
```